# why PCIe TLP header has "Last DW BE" and "First DW BE"?

Tags: linux, kernel, fpga, pci

I've met a problem related to PCIe. I use a driver to write `0x12345678` to BAR0+offset, and use Xilinx Chipscope to see the waveform. On our Intel Rangeley board, we see TLP payload is split into two DWs, that is `00_00_00_78 56_34_12_00`, while on a dell PC, we see only one DW in payload. I'm sure both case conform the PCIe specification.

But I really wonder, why should PCIe specification has this kind of design, that is "Last DW BE" and "First DW BE" in 2nd DW of TLP header?

Comment: What is the linux system details on both systems (uname -r)? Also, what is the offset for the test?

Comment: Hi @JonathanDrolet, on our Intel C2000 Rangeley board, it's windriver linux x86-64, and the offset is 0x3567. I can't remember the exact value of offset we tested on dell PC some days ago, but I think the dell PC is aslo x86-64. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Your question refers to memory request PCI transfers, which for your question can be trimmed down to 4 parameters: address, length, first dword byte enable and last dword byte enable.

**Address and length are dword-aligned**, i.e. `address[1:0] = 0` by PCI specification. So what happens if you want to write a single byte? Or at a non dword-aligned address such as 0x3567? You are force to write at least 1 dword, but you do not want to erase the adjacent bytes. That's where first DW BE comes into play. For example, to write 1 byte to address 0x3567, you would have:

- Address = 0x3564, since dword-aligned
- Length = 1 dword, minimum size allowed
- First DW BE = 0b1000, only fourth byte valid
- Last DW BE = 0b0000, no byte valid

Similarly, last DW BE comes into play when your transfer doesn't end on a dword boundary. For example, if you want to write 27 bytes at address 6:

- Address = 4, since dword-aligned
- Length = 7, since it must be a dword multiple
- First DW BE = 0b1100, since at address 4 only the upper 2 bytes are valid (addresses 4 and 5 invalid)
- Last DW BE = 0b0001, since at address 4+6*4 only the first byte is valid (addresses 4+6*4+1, 4+6*4+2 and 4+6*4+3 invalid)

Comment: Yes, just see in Spec. It's exactly you described. I'm new to PCIe, thanks for help buddy!